# What do Lisp macros have over functions that optionally evaluate their arguments?

Tags: macros, scheme, lisp

### Context

I've been learning some Lisp (Scheme, primarily) over the past few days, drawn by the allure of the sheer power said to be afforded by these languages. Of course, macros are the thing that are supposed to be the most powerful feature that this power is based on. Learning to use macros, by the accounts that I've heard, is much like first learning how to use first-class functions. When you learn how to use first-class functions, they start to be applicable everywhere, to the point of it being very hard to go back to imperative languages with no such concept. Writing pre-lambda Java code, for example, is very painful for me now.

Given this analogy of first-class functions, I was quite shocked to discover that Lisp macros are not first-class.

For instance, I can easily use a first-class function in Scheme in the following way:

```lisp
(map (lambda (x) (+ x 1)) '(1 2 3))
```

Now replace that lambda with the name of some macro, and Scheme will complain that you're using a macro as a variable name. Given that I can't pass macros around like data, they are definitely second-class. Granted, I'm not even certain how a random macro should work in that scenario, but that's beside the point.

### Alternative?

I'm always wary of a construct that is compile-time only, because that usually signals some limitation in the language. So, I naturally wonder how macros could be first-class runtime objects. We can sorta do this with lambdas already. For instance, in this Scheme code, both `or` and `eval-or` will print `1` and return `#t`, but `eval-or` requires apostrophes on the call site:

```lisp
(or
  (begin (display "1") (= 5 5))
  (begin (display "2") (= 5 6)))

(define eval-or 
  (lambda (a b)
    (if (eval a) #t (eval b))))

(eval-or
  '(begin (display "1") (= 5 5))
  '(begin (display "2") (= 5 6)))
```

I am not acquainted with the niceties of `eval`, but I do know that it doesn't preserve the lexical scope. But perhaps if we added some sort of special construct to Scheme, say `lazy-lambda`, that allows you to choose when to evaluate an argument, while still preserving all the scoping properties of normal lambdas? Then you could do something like:

```lisp
(define lazy-or
  (lazy-lambda (a b)
    (if (value a) #t (value b))))

(lazy-or
  (begin (display "1") (= 5 5))
  (begin (display "2") (= 5 6)))
```

It seems to me that this should be able to perform all of the same operations that a hygienic macro can. For instance, I can create DSLs or entirely new forms of control flow, just as macros can. It's not using `eval`, so I can reference things in the lexical scope of the caller. But moreover, it's also entirely first-class--I can pass `lazy-or` to functions just like I could with a first-class function like `+`. It looks like the power of Lisp macros, but fully first-class and runtime.

### The question

Of course, if it were that simple, someone would have thought of it already, now wouldn't they? I fully expect that there may be some fundamental flaw in this idea (even more so given my minimal Lisp experience); if so, I'd be much obliged if someone could point it out.

Otherwise, can anyone give me a concrete example where a macro can do something really important that this hypothetical `lazy-lambda` cannot?

---

(Note: Not a duplicate of [Are Lisp macros just syntactic sugar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74609276/are-lisp-macros-just-syntactic-sugar) or [What makes Lisp macros so special?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267862/what-makes-lisp-macros-so-special). I'm asking about a hypothetical language feature not found in Lisp that is possibly better than macros without loss of important usability, not asking about the differences between macros and functions)

Comment: The mechanism you are proposing isn't really clear, but I think that the answer to the top question is that these types of mechanisms fell out of favor long ago due to problems with compilation and a tendency to be error-prone. There are some who have continued to pursue these ideas, e.g. [John Shutt](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/4093) [PhD Thesis](https://digital.wpi.edu/concern/etds/ht24wj541?locale=en) and [other researchers](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2303.12254.pdf).

Comment: @adabsurdum Thanks for those links, they look like useful reading to learn more about these sorts of ideas.

Comment: Here is another link I found to a [discussion of fexprs in Kernel](https://eighty-twenty.org/2011/09/29/fexprs-remain-inscrutable), the language designed by John Shutt. Both Shutt and Mitchell Wand show up in the comments section. I think that the main "power" conferred by fexprs or by what you are proposing is their first-class nature which might mean an increase in expressive capabilities in some circumstances, but Kent Pitman's point seemed to be that macros are _adequate_ for the task (creation of special forms) without the drawbacks of fexprs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `lazy-lambda` construct provides what is really *normal-order evaluation* in a language which is generally *applicative-order*.  It does this in the same way that this was done in many ancient Lisps: by saying that you need to ask for the value of some object explicitly, in your case via your `value` form.

(A **normal-order** language evaluates arguments to a function at the point their value is needed, while an **applicative-order** language evaluates them at the point the function is called.  A normal-order language may therefore *never* evaluate some function arguments, while an applicative-order language always does.)

As I said, this is an old idea.  The traditional name for it is that this kind of function is a **FEXPR**, where a normal function would be an **EXPR**.

Here's how FEXPRs were done in ancient Lisp:

1. require the language to be dynamically scoped, which means that `eval` will be able to see variable bindings;
2. a FEXPR is then handed the *source* of its arguments, and uses `eval` as needed.

This is as horrible as it sounds, and in particular there are three implications which follow from an implementation like this.

1. Such languages could never really be fully compiled, because FEXPRs needed to be handed the source of their arguments.
2. Such languages needed to use dynamic scope, not lexical scope: if a FEXPR was handed an argument which was `x`, then the value of the variable `x` needed to be available to `eval`.
3. A FEXPR could be abused as follows: instead of simply evaluating its argument, it could look at it (since it had the source which was just an s-expression), rewrite it into some other thing, and evaluate *that*.

(In fact ancient Lisps usually had much more incoherent semantics than this.)

Well, let's consider a less horrible implementation of FEXPRs:

1. a FEXPR will get arguments which are 'promises' which encapsulate a form which can be evaluated in the right environment;
2. and there is a function, `force` which will force the evaluation of a promise.

This can all be done in such a way as to make lexical scope possible and allow compilation.  The obvious implementation is that a promise is just an object wrapping procedure, and `force` arranges for the procedure to be called, perhaps memoizing its value.

So now let's see what you can, and can not do with these rationalised FEXPRs.  Let's say it's 1965 and you're getting bored writing

```lisp
((lambda (x ...)
    ...)
 ...
 ...)
```

every time you want to bind a variable.  You decide you'd like to write

```lisp
(with ((x ...) ...)
  ...)
```

instead.  Can you write `with` using FEXPRs?  I'll wait.

Well, the answer, obviously, is no, you can't.  You can't because the first subform of `with` isn't a thing that can be evaluated at all: it's a new bit of syntax.  You *could* write it with old awful FEXPRs but then you're back to dynamic scope, inability to compile, tentacles everywhere and so on.

Instead, you have to write `with` (whose real name, of course, is `let`) another way.  You define it as corresponding to one of a number of functions whose domains and ranges are *source code*.  `let` is implemented by a function whose argument is a fragment of source code written in a language which includes `let` and whose value is a fragment of source code in a language which doesn't.

And these functions, of course, are macros.  And, critically, *you can't do what such functions can do with FEXPRs* (unless you are willing to accept the horrors described above, which you are not).

So that's why you need macros: *macros allow you to build languages, FEXPRs do not*.

This view of macros as functions between languages, once you understand it, really gives a very powerful insight as to what they are, and the power they give you.  That power is the ability to treat programming as the process of *building a language in which to solve a problem*, not of forcing the problem into some existing, inadequate, language.

---

**Note 1.**  It's worth noting that in Common Lisp macros are quite explicitly implemented by functions whose domain and range is source code as described above.  A macro is implemented by a perfectly ordinary function associated with its name, which is called during macroexpansion with an argument which is an s-expression (and an environment object) and which returns another s-expression.

**Note 2.**  It's quite easy to implement the rationalised FEXPRs I describe above using macros.  One such, for CL, is [here](https://tfeb.github.io/tfeb-lisp-toys/#not-fexprs-fex).  If you look at this you'll fairly quickly come to realise some of the problems with FEXPRs.  For instance, given

```
(define (f g a)
  (g (expensive a)))
```

Then, if FEXPRs are first class, `g` might be one.  When should `expensive` be called then?  If you're going to get this right, then every function call where the function is not statically known has to handle the case that the function might be a FEXPR.  And don't even ask what `apply` should do, because I have no idea.

Historical Lisps which had FEXPRs were not semantically coherent enough to worry about problems like this: their answer would likely be 'if you do this, then the magic smoke will escape'.

Comment: This explains very well what I just learned in the comments to another answer; I wanted my cake and be able to eat it to by pulling the lexical scope into the function, but there's still no way to extend the lexical scope out of a function because that's no longer lexical scoping.  And no, I really, really don't want dynamic scoping, thank you very much :)

Comment: The claims in this answer are false. FEXPRS can do everything that macros do. (And more.)  But they are not functions either. FEXPRS are to macros what interpretation is to compilation. This question could easily be "what can I do with FEXPRS that I cannot do with functions?   FEXPRS can be lexically scoped. If a lexically scoped Lisp interpreter is extended with user-defined special operators, those will be lexical FEXPRS.  They will receive a form to interpret and an environment, and that environment will be lexical.

Comment: Agreed. `FEXPRS` can in a interpreted language be lexically scoped. The main problem with them is optimization and having to expand code also in runtime. The [Kernel language](https://web.cs.wpi.edu/~jshutt/kernel.html) is a lexical lisp with first class lexical macros/fexpr and to visualize what is a fexr all of them is prefixed with `$`. eg. `$let`, `$if`, ... and `$lambda` isn't a primitive form as it can be defined by using `$vau`

Comment: @Kaz The claims in this answer are true *for Lisp* (or Scheme).  They might be false for some language with about as much relation to Lisp as FORTRAN has to  ML.  In plainer words: I was not talking about Kernel, I would have said I was if I was.

Comment: Modern Lisps tend not to have fexprs; Scheme doesn't.  Whether the language is dynamically scoped or lexical, fexprs can express almost everything that a macro can express, directly, with the same syntax. About the only thing fexpr's cannot do is pull in material from the compilation environment. A macro could interpolate the build machine's host name into the target code, making that name available on the target machine. A fexpr would be run from source on the target machine, having no memory of any build machine.

Comment: @Kaz I am interested in languages which can be efficiently compiled.  In such a language decisions about the semantics of source code must be made at compile time, and it must also be possible for the compiler to make decisions about the possibility of reference to lexical bindings (which are not always 'any binding may be referenced').  FEXPRs which allow that must, I am pretty sure, be unable to do things that macros can do (and I see no evidence to contradict that in Kernel).  However this is not the place to discuss this: you can contact me elsewhere if you wish to continue.

Comment: FEXPRS are special operators that are are provided by the Lisp program itself. They follow whatever scoping the Lisp dialect uses. If the Lisp dialect's special operators have an environment parameter representing a lexical scope, then the FEXPRs will have that same parameter, and be able to do things like peek into the environment to see what variables are already defined, and extend that environment with new variables before interpreting code.  The FEXPR doesn't itself "see" the lexical environment, but it has has access to it as an object it receives as an argument.

Comment: @Kaz I am fully aware of that, thanks, and it in no way addresses my concerns, as I suspect you well know.  I am not going to discuss this further with you as there clearly is no purpose in doing so, least of all here.

Answer (score 5):

> *Otherwise, can anyone give me a concrete example where a macro can do something really important that this hypothetical lazy-lambda cannot?*

What a macro can do is reshape the language ways that aren't just evaluation control.

The important thing about the arguments of a macro isn't that they aren't evaluated, but that they are source code to which a *meaning* has not been assigned (and for that reason they have not been evaluated). The macro can analyze the arguments and produce a meaning which is other than just "this is evaluated, whereas that isn't".

We have to take a step back here though: "macro arguments" are an illusion. The classic non-hygienic macro system simulates parameters. Under the hood, the macro name is associated with an expander function. That function takes the entire macro invocation form as one argument. The *defmacro* operator is itself a macro which writes the code that performs the destructuring which makes it look like the macro has parameters that take arguments.

Macros have been used to implement:

- object-oriented programming systems
- domain-specific languages for looping and iteration
- pattern matching notations
- assignable places

Example of macro-based pattern-matching in a Lisp dialect:

```
5> (if-match (likes @x @x) '(1 2 2) x)
nil
6> (if-match (likes @x @x) '(1 2 3) x)
nil
7> (if-match (likes @x @x) '(1 2 2) x)
nil
8> (if-match (likes @x @x) '(likes 2 2) x)
2
```

Under the hood:

```
9> (expand '(if-match (likes @x @x) '(likes 2 2) x))
(let* (#:result-0112
       x)
  (if (if (consp '(likes 2 2))
        (let ((#:g0106 (car '(likes 2 2)))
              (#:g0107 (cdr '(likes 2 2))))
          (if (equal #:g0106 'likes)
            (if (consp #:g0107)
              (let ((#:g0108 (car #:g0107))
                    (#:g0109 (cdr #:g0107)))
                (sys:setq x #:g0108)
                (if (consp #:g0109)
                  (let ((#:g0110 (car #:g0109))
                        (#:g0111 (cdr #:g0109)))
                    (if (equal #:g0110 x)
                      (if (equal #:g0111 '())
                        (progn (sys:setq #:result-0112
                                 x)
                          t))))))))))
    #:result-0112
    ()))
```

We can see that whereas the `'(likes 2 2)` and `x` arguments of the `if-match` macro make straightforward appearances in the expansion (they are evaluated), the `(likes @x @x)` pattern expression is not simply evaluated, lazily or otherwise. It turned into code: code that traverses the input object and performs the tests which confirm whether the object matches the pattern, as well as preparing the value of `x` in that event.

As a side note, you might think the code looks gross, but the compiler gets it down to one instruction, thanks to `(likes 2 2)` being a literal constant:

```
10> (flow '(if-match (likes @x @x) '(likes 2 2) x)
      compile-toplevel
      disassemble)
data:
    0: 2
syms:
code:
    0: 10000400 end d0
instruction count:
    1
#<sys:vm-desc: 90eff30>
```

Comment: That's interesting; I didn't know that macros didn't automatically destructure arguments.  Still, I feel like I could do pattern matching with `lazy-lambda`.  Since the arguments haven't been evaluated yet, they must still be lists, and I can treat them as such and reorganize them.  Almost certainly, the macros would make it easier on the compiler to optimize things, but I'm still not convinced that I've lost any power with `lazy-lambda`.

Comment: @v-rob You can't do pattern matching with `lazy-lambda`, as defined, such that it generates the code in-place, and binds lexical variables at the call site to the pieces pulled from the matched object. There is no question that we can have a function (even an eagerly evaluated one) like `(if-match '(likes @x @x) '(likes 2 2))` that will return, for instance, `((x . 2))`. We can make that function call another function to pass it arguments: `(if-match '(likes $1 $1) '(likes 2 2) (lambda (arg) ...))` where `if-match` analyzes the pattern, and calls the lambda with the extracted `$1`, `$2`, ...

Comment: The functional `if-match` will be processing the pattern when it's called, rather than compiling it up-front to code that gets optimized.

Comment: Hmm, that's a good point--I can pull variables into with `lazy-lambda` from the outside scope, but I can't expose new variables from inside the `lazy-lambda` into another scope, at least not with the way I've formulated it.  That's definitely an area where macros have something over `lazy-lambda`.  I think that answers my question then.  Although the answer mentioning `FEXPR` and another comment about reformulation of those ideas has given me more food for thought (and reading).

Comment: @v-rob Also, note that "not the way I've formulated it" just means "not where I currently placed the goalposts".  `lazy-lambda` is understood to be a special operator. As such, its definition can be updated to anything that any imaginable macro can do. Functional languages have pattern matching, without macros; they defined the syntax and semantics for that at the implementation level via their "special operators".

Answer (score 3):

I think `lazy-lambda` is a concept known as [FEXPR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fexpr), ie. a function whose arguments are not evaluated until requested. In particular, the linked article says:

> In 1998, Mitchell Wand showed that adding a fexpr device to lambda calculus — a device that suppresses rewriting of operands — produces a formal system with a trivial equational theory, rendering it impossible to make source-to-source optimizations without a whole-program analysis.

Comment: This is interesting, but it also seems to imply that `FEXPR` was limited by the dynamic scoping of Lisps of the time.  I wonder if a Lisp with lexical scoping could avoid these sorts of issues.  It also says that `FEXPR` predates macros, but are macros really superior in power?

Comment: v-rob: what does 'power' mean? It can have different meanings! More expressive? Faster code? Macros had replaced Fexprs because they were easily compilable. Fast code was very important for people writing actual applications in Lisp. Wikipedia gives some background on Fexprs. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fexpr

Comment: I think the example was using lexical scoping on the article, and basically each argument in a function call becomes a closure in case it is evaluated lazily as far as I know (but Haskell does something like that too). Macros as a term rewriting tool also can represent new binding constructs with a user-friendly syntax and feels easier to reason about imo

Comment: @RainerJoswig I mean power the same way one means power when talking about first-class functions; I think this was clear from the original question.  Can I do things with macros that I can't do with FEXPR?  Can I do things with FEXPR that I can't with macros?  If so, what?  I need evidence before I'll believe that macros give more power over FEXPR or vice-versa.

Comment: I think it has been several times mentioned that macros can be easily compiled. One trades 'power to compute things at runtime' against 'power to create faster code'.

Comment: @RainerJoswig I don't deny that macros may give better speed.  But if I wanted that kind of power, I could use C++, which I am very familiar with.  I explicitly wanted to learn Lisp for increased power of expression, not power of performance.

Comment: If FEXPRS are resurrected in a lexically scoped Lisp, they have to be lexically scoped. FEXPRS are application-defined special operators. If a built-in special operator receives a lexical environment argument, but an application-defined operator does not, then it is not the same kind of "citizen" in the language.

Comment: FEXPRS don't answer this question because it can easily be "what can macros and fexprs do that I cannot do with lazy evaluation".

Answer (score 1):

Your code:

```
(or
  (begin (display "1") (= 5 5))
  (begin (display "2") (= 5 6)))

(define eval-or 
  (lambda (a b)
    (if (eval a) #t (eval b))))

(eval-or
  '(begin (display "1") (= 5 5))
  '(begin (display "2") (= 5 6)))
```

**Avoiding EVAL**

There is no need to write that using EVAL and pass lists around.
That's usually done in Scheme like this.

```
(define my-or 
  (lambda (a b)
    (if (a) #t (b))))

(my-or
  (lambda ()
    (display "1")
    (= 5 5))
  (lambda ()
    (display "2")
    (= 5 6)))
```

**Macros can be used in an interpreted Scheme**

> I'm always wary of a construct that is compile-time only, because that usually signals some limitation in the language.

Macros are not compile-time only. One can use macros in source-level interpreted Scheme implementation just fine. Macros can be expanded during runtime in an interpreted Scheme.

It's a feature of macros is that they **can** be expanded at compile-time.

But macros have the same limitation like built-in constructs: `if` is not something one can pass around. We can't write

```
(foo if)
```

and pass `if` around. Similar for other built-in syntax in Scheme: `if`, `set!`, `lambda`, `quote`, `let-syntax`, ...

**A case for macros...**

> Otherwise, can anyone give me a concrete example where a macro can do something really important that this hypothetical lazy-lambda cannot?

How would you implement `lazy-lambda`?

```
(define lazy-or
  (lazy-lambda (a b)
    (if (value a) #t (value b))))`
```

`lazy-lambda` can't be written as a function, since it has special evaluation, unlike what a function call does.

Now you have basically two ways to implement `lazy-lambda`:

a) you can implement it into your language as a built-in construct

b) you can try to write it as macro

in b) there is is this idea of a user extension of the language via macros again...

Comment: This answer misses the point; I wasn't proposing `eval` as a good idea; it's just the most direct way to make something look like a macro without leaving the realm of functions.  Indeed, it's a very bad idea.  Moreover, I was using `lazy-lambda` as a concept of a built-in construct that replaces macros as a built-in construct.  You really haven't shown me how macros can do something that `lazy-lambda` can't.

Comment: "lazy-lambda as a concept of a built-in construct that replaces macros as a built-in construct."- the example shows nothing of that. macros have much broader use cases than "lazy-lambda" has. In fact lazy-lambda would not need to be a "built-in" construct, one would first to think of implementing as a macro. "You really haven't shown me how macros can do something that lazy-lambda can't". You have not shown what lazy-lambda does and how it should work. Thus we can only speculate...

Comment: @v-rob You really need to come up with a sketch of what lazy-lambda does / how it should work and what `value`does. One of the practical goals is that Lisp can be compiled to efficient code. For an article why macros in Lisp dialects have been replaced other mechanism (FEXPRs): https://www.nhplace.com/kent/Papers/Special-Forms.html

Comment: In the interests of keeping the question short, I left `lazy-lambda` fairly unspecified, but I believe I gave enough for evaluation of the idea: it's dynamic and runtime unlike macros which are compile time, but also unlike `eval` because it preserves the lexical scoping of variables when passed to `value`.  What can I do with macros that I couldn't do with this kind of thing?  If there's anything else behavioral that I need to specify for `lazy-lambda`, please tell me exactly what is missing.

Comment: 'What can I do with macros that I couldn't do with this kind of thing?' Do you know what you can do with macros? Macros are source code transformers. A macro can for example transform infix notation to prefix notation. It can compile a PASCAL like syntax to to Lisp. It can rewrite source code in arbitrary ways. I don't know what your LAZY-LAMBDA can do... "because it preserves the lexical scoping of variables when passed to value." How so?

Comment: I know perfectly well what a macro can do.  I could compile infix notation using `lazy-lambda`--take the list, transform it from infix to prefix, and evaluate it with `value`.  By preserving lexical scoping, I mean that if there is a variable `x` like `(let ((x 7) (infix (x + 5)))` where `infix` is a `lazy-lambda` that translates infix form to prefix form, then the `x` in `(x + 5)` knows that it refers to the `x` in the `let`, making it much like a closure, whereas `eval` can only find this information through the dynamic environment.

Answer (score 0):

I think the idea that a macro not being a first class function is not the right way to think about macros. Macros run at compile time. What makes this special is you can parse Lisp expressions at compile time and create whatever Lisp code you wish. That means you can implement new language features as you see fit. Rather than having to figure out how to use Lisp to solve a problem you just modify Lisp so your problem is more easily coded.

A function in Lisp cannot change the order in which the arguments are evaluated. Suppose you need a function f where in (f a b) you need to evaluate b before a at run time. A normally defined function relies on the REPL to evaluate the arguments but the function f cannot control the run time. With a macro you could control the run time.

Suppose you need a function that sets the values of 2 variables (set2q x y val). A definition of a normal function interprets each argument and therefore cannot assign to the variable, so there is no way to define set2q as a function. You need a macro to do that.

Perhaps I should just take your proposal; macros allow you to implement lazy-lambda.

Comment: My `lazy-lambda` allows changing the order of argument evaluation; it's as simple as `(begin (value a) (value b))` vs. `(begin (value b) (value a))` vs. `(begin (value a))` without evaluating `b`.  Moreover, I could implement a `setq2` if I extended the concept of `lazy-lambda` to allow capturing variables, similar to how I understand hygienic macros can allow you to.  This answer doesn't show me how macros are better than `lazy-lambda`, only how they're better than functions alone.

Comment: Rob, you’ve expressed how lazy-lambda could do something. I suggest lisp macros are better because you could implement lazy-lambda now.

Comment: I have seen no evidence that I could do such a thing.  The macro would be a thin wrapper around `eval`, which has the problems I mentioned before.

Comment: "a function that sets the values of 2 variables (set2q x y val) ... there is no way to define set2q as a function. You need a macro to do that." *that* depends on a language and its definition for "variables" and scope discipline. if it's a lisp with symbols you can very well use a function for that, like `(set 'x val)` to set the value of a symbol `'x`, and use `x` as a variable.

Comment: Will, you proved the point. (set 'x val) sets the value of x, but you have to use quote.